# I am having trouble with a computer science program that I am working on. I finished the coding but I am having trouble with my Runner Class

Tags: java, arrays, jgrasp

Given a provided array, determine how many groups of a specified size exist.
For the array [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7] , there are 7 groups with at least one, 3 groups with at
least 2, and 3 groups with at least 3. A group is a series of same values. 1 1 1 is a group of 3, but it also is
a group of 1 and 2. To count as a group, all values must be the same. 1 1 1 is a group of 3 because there
are 3 1s in a row.

Sample output:
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8]
size 1 count == 7

size 2 count == 6

size 3 count == 5

size 4 count == 3

size 5 count == 2

size 6 count == 1

My main code:

```
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

        import static java.lang.System.*;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class ArrayStats {
      int[] numArray;
      int number;

      public ArrayStats(int[] a) {
        setArray(a);
      }

      public void setArray(int[] a) {
        numArray = a;
      }

      public int getNumGroupsOfSize() {
        int cnt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length - 1; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] == numArray[i + 1])
        cnt++;
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++) {
          if (cnt == i)
            number = cnt;
          else if (cnt == 1)
            number = 1;
        }
      }
      return number;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return "size count" + " == " + getNumGroupsOfSize() + Arrays.toString(numArray);
    }
    }
```

My runner code:

```
public class ArrayStatsRunner
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
       int[] one = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
       ArrayStats test = new ArrayStats(one);
       System.out.println(test.toString());
       System.out.println("size 1 count == "+test.getNumGroupsOfSize(1));
       System.out.println("size 2 count == "+test.getNumGroupsOfSize(2));
       System.out.println("size 3 count == "+test.getNumGroupsOfSize(3));
       System.out.println("size 4 count == "+test.getNumGroupsOfSize(4));
       System.out.println("size 5 count == "+test.getNumGroupsOfSize(5));
       System.out.println("size 6 count == "+test.getNumGroupsOfSize(6));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Your runner code doesn't compile. It's impossible for that code to produce that output since you don't actually supply "size" anywhere. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sounds more like you want us to complete the code for you, without attempting a complete solution yourself.

Comment: I have attempted it lots of times and couldn't be able to run it properly.

Comment: How about you post the code of an attempt that actually **compiles**? An attempt where the code actually tries to count for a particular **size**?

Comment: What is the parameter 'one' you are passing to the constructor of ArrayStats?

Comment: Guys, I am sorry for the confusion I am learning arrays, and it complicated for me. I came here to get some help or information, so I can try and learn on what I have done wrong. I hate getting answers without even trying it. I am honest here.

Answer (score 0):

There is couple of problems with this method:

```
  public int getNumGroupsOfSize() {
int cnt = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < numArray.length - 1; x++) { 
if (numArray[x] == numArray[x + 1]); 
cnt++;
for (int y = 2; y <= 9; y++) { 
  if (cnt == y)
    number = cnt;
  else if (cnt == 1)
    number = 1;
}
  }
  return number;
}
```

Here is only some of the problems:
1. lets look at the second line:

```
for (int x = 0; x < numArray.length - 1; x++)
```

`x < numArray.length - 1` will cause a problem because you wont check the last index of the array. 
side note: it's a custom to use the letter i (index) and not x or y. If you are doing for loop inside for loop the custom is to do:

```
     for (int i = 0; i < numArray.length - 1; i++)
        {
        for (int j = 0; j < numArray.length - 1; j++)
        {
        //some line of code
        }}
```

2. This line of code `if (numArray[x] == numArray[x + 1]);`will do nothing because you put `;` in the end of the row. Even if   `numArray[x] == numArray[x + 1]`is true it wont do `cnt++;`.

Please check and learn from this code:

```
 public class Main {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int[] nums = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
    System.out.println(+getGroupSize(nums,9)); //prints 1

    System.out.println("size two== "+groupCount(nums,2)); //prints 6
    System.out.println("size three== "+groupCount(nums,3));//prints 5


    int[] nums2={1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,5,6,7};
    System.out.println(+getGroupSize(nums2,1)); //prints 3
    System.out.println("size two== "+groupCount(nums2,2)); //prints 3
    System.out.println("size two== "+groupCount(nums2,3)); //prints 3
    System.out.println("size two== "+groupCount(nums2,5)); //prints 0

}



public static int getGroupSize(int[] array, int specificNumber  ) {
    /*This method prints the number of times a specific number exist in a array.
    example: if the input of specificNumber is 3. in this array:
    int[] nums = {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 9, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8};
    the method will return 5.
    if the number is 9 is method will return 1. if number is 7 the method will return 3
    */
    int groupCount = 0; //counts the number of times a specific number exist in a array
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) { //this for loop will check every number in  array
        if (array[i] ==specificNumber) {
            groupCount++;// if the current number of the array is the specificNumber, then the count will do plus one
        }
    }
    return groupCount; //return the count
}


public static int groupCount(int[] array, int groupSize)
{
    int groupCount=0;
    int currentGroup=array[0]; //initialize the current group to be the first group of the array

    if(getGroupSize(array, array[currentGroup])>=groupSize)
    { //check the size of the first group
        groupCount++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] !=currentGroup) { //checks if the current number is equal to the current group value
            if(getGroupSize(array, array[i])>=groupSize)
            {
                groupCount++;
            }
            currentGroup=array[i]; // restart the currentGroup to be the current valume of the array

        }
    } //end of for loop
    return groupCount;
}

private static void print(int [] array) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("size " +i+" group:" +groupCount(array, i));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I have updated my main code. But the runner I have a compile error that says "ArrayStatsRunner.java:14: error: method getNumGroupsOfSize in class ArrayStats cannot be applied to given types;" and I don't understand on what I did wrong to get this error.

Comment: Thats mean that  getNumGroupsOfSize  require a parameter and you aren't passing one. Look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169606/method-in-class-cannot-be-applied-to-given-types